# useRef TypeScript - not assignable to type LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I am trying to use `useRef` with TypeScript but am having some trouble.

With my `RefObject` (I assume) I need to access `current`. (ie `node.current`)

I have tried the following

- `const node: RefObject<HTMLElement> = useRef(null);`
- `const node = useRef<HTMLElement | null>(null);`

but when I go to set the `ref` I am always told that X `is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement> | undefined'.`

`return <div ref={ node }>{ children }</div>`

Edit: this should not be restricted to any one type of element so not just `HTMLDivElement | HTMLFormElement | HTMLInputElement`

Edit: This should work as an example

```
import React, { useRef, RefObject } from 'react';

function Test() 
{
    // const node = useRef(null);
    // const node: RefObject<HTMLElement> = useRef(null);
    const node = useRef<HTMLElement | null>(null);

    if (
        node &&
        node.current &&
        node.current.contains()
    ){ console.log("current accessed")}

    return <div ref={ node }></div>
}
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Just import React:

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

function Test() {
    const node = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    if (
        node &&
        node.current &&
        node.current.contains()
    ){ console.log("current accessed")}

    return <div ref={node}></div>
}
```

I made an update. Use `HTMLDivElement` as generic parameter instead of `HTMLElement | null`. Also, `contains` expects an argument.

**UPDATE**
`useRef` expects generic argument of DOM element type. You don't need to use `| null` because `RefObject` already knows that `current` might be null.

See next type:

```js
interface RefObject<T> {
  readonly current: T | null
}
```

TS & React are smart enough to figure out that your ref might be null

Comment: I appreciate the answer and this does work with the example I provided but unfortunately I need to add to my example. My apologies

Comment: I have modified the example if you wish to modify your answer

Comment: thank you this does work. If you could, please provide additional details as to *why* this works and why one should use this interface. thank you

Comment: Thanks for the update and I will accept this answer. I think I understand the part about `null` I am a bit more interested as to why `HTMLDivElement` is able to handle the `ref` but `HTMLElement` is not

Comment: HTMLElement interface is a parent interface for all html elements. It does not work because you are unable to create HTMLElement literally. You can only create HTMLDivElement, HTMLSpanElement, HTMLAnchorElement etc .... So React/JSX only can accept HTML{element}Element. For instance, it complains that HTMLElement does not have `allign` property. Hover mouse on ref attribute in your IDE press Ctrl and click on ref attribute. It should redirect you to ref types

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine that doesn't make sense.

Isn't it supposed to be doing something like this

`const htmlElement: HTMLElement = new HTMLDivElement();` underneath?

This is essentially polymorphism, so why is useRef behaving differently?

Comment: @George you need to provide explicit generic because you use `null` as an initial value

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine it still doesn't make sense to me
`let element: HTMLElement | null = null;
element = new HTMLDivElement()`. This is valid no?

Comment: @George but rhis is not how useRef works

Answer (score 214):

None of the above worked for me, but turns out the solution was quite simple...

All I was doing wrong was not explicitly including "null" as the parameter in the useRef initialization (it expects null, not undefined).
Also you CANNOT use "HTMLElement" as your ref type, you have to be more specific, so for me it was "HTMLDivElement" for example).

So working code for me was something like this:

```
const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

return <div ref={ref}> Some Content... </div>
```

Comment: Since I am using `createRef` rather than `useRef` I cannot initiate it with `null`, but I added it in the union of the possible types my ref can be (since my component can render one of a handful of sub-components). This did the trick.

It ended up something like this:
`private inputRef = React.createRef<CustomTextArea & CustomInput & null>()`

Comment: setting null as the default was the trick. Thank you.

Comment: Great as this is, my use case requires an array of refs, I'm not sure how to type for this. When I type null I continue to get the error...

Answer (score 6):

The same stands for the `<svg>` elements:

```
const ref = useRef<SVGSVGElement>(null)
...
<svg ref={ref} />
```

Answer (score 5):

I came here looking for help with an iframe ref. Perhaps this solution will help someone else that's looking for the same thing. I replaced `HTMLDivElement` with `HTMLIFrameElement` so:

```
const node = useRef<HTMLIFrameElement>(null);
```

Comment: I just had to add that default `null` value. Immediately fixed my errors

Answer (score 4):

```
selfref = React.createRef<HTMLInputElement>()
```

I give the exacted TS Type, then the editor passed the check. it works nice now.

Answer (score 3):

After looking at all answers here I am not sure that any of them answer/explain the problem fully. In this case problem is two fold:

- we need to use a different HTML interface object -> *HTMLDivElement*
- we need to pass a default value to the reference initialization

React *useRef* function actually has 3 different signatures (in React 16.8):

If the passed default value is the same type as the generic type

```
function useRef\<T>(initialValue: T): MutableRefObject<T>;
```

If we pass a default value of the same type as the generic type OR null (as spotted by many responses here)

```
function useRef\<T>(initialValue: T|null): RefObject<T>;
```

If we pass no default values AND/OR we pass no generic type

```
function useRef\<T = undefined>(): MutableRefObject<T | undefined>;
```

The real issue comes down to incompatibility of *MutableRefObject* and *LegacyRef*. I am guessing React team did changes to the data types of references and therefor we have multiple signatures and types of references based on what we pass.

It would be nice to get a nicer error message from react eslint at least as the generic TS error message we get isn't enough to immediately spot what's wrong.

Tl;dr: passing *null* as the default value in *useRef* object will give us back the reference object that both satisfies *MutableRefObject* and *LegacyRef* (probably)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same error and there was a suggestion to convert to unknown first:

```
ref={inputRef as unknown as RefObject<HTMLTextAreaElement>}
```

Answer (score 1):

Key is to use HTMLElement and undefined for initialization

```
const node = useRef<HTMLElement>();
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can explicitly cast:

```
const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>();
...
<input
      ref={ref as RefObject<HTMLInputElement>}
      ...
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting this error in typescript is because you need to type the ref.current and not just the ref

example:

```
const ref = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

Component(props: {ref?: {current: HTMLDivElement}})
```