# Using forwardRef in other component got type error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I got this error:

> Type 'ForwardedRef<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement>'

```
import React from "react";

const Other = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <h1>Other</h1>
    </div>
  );
});

export default Other;
```

Is this the right usage?

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-shadow-5ul13e?file=/src/Other.tsx:0-172

Comment: in App.ts try `const myRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>();`

Comment: I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66963289/useref-typescript-not-assignable-to-type-legacyrefhtmldivelement but doesn't work

Comment: @Layhout not working

Comment: i opened your demo, there's no error.

Comment: in App.ts, i imported `useEffect` and added `useEffect(()=>{console.log(myRef.current)},[])`. and i get the element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply make sure to provide type arguments to `forwardRef`, as shown for example [here](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/forward_and_create_ref/):

```
import React from "react";

const Other = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, unknown>((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>{/* Okay */}
      <h1>Other</h1>
    </div>
  );
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AoctCAOwGd4B5GACySjgF5FiYA6TNADuKKABNkmADwAJACoBZADIARYADcAogBskIJDRgAaOAFcaAaxoQhNAHwAKB2Bxg6JopgCUXO3ADe5HBwRDCmUDRwDkHBcFJiGiFImJz+ngC+djGxcSwAjHbMbFBSAPT5WTllCeqVcF4U6Q3kQA)

Answer (score 3):

Initialise `useRef` with `null` initially and type `<HTMLDivElement>`. Also, apply type `<HTMLDivElement>` to `forwardRef` as well. Check on mount if `ref` is assigned correctly.

Here is the [Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-rumple-lgor39?file=/src/App.tsx)