# Typing for an Array of Refs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, ref

I'm trying to create a component that allows for the user to click outside it. To do this I need to create a ref for each component that requires the functionality. This is what I'm trying to type for.

I'm struggling to find a fix for the error `HTMLDivElement | null is not assignable to type Legacy<HTMLDivElement> | undefined`. I've looked through the SO thread here and I'm still not having any success.

[useRef TypeScript - not assignable to type LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66963289/useref-typescript-not-assignable-to-type-legacyrefhtmldivelement)

Here is my code currently. Please see line 127 => https://tsplay.dev/mxypbW

Comment: **ref={ref} className="flex gap-2 bg-yellow-400"** the ref here is a htmldivelement not a ref you can deleted **className="flex gap-2 bg-yellow-400"**

Comment: Hi Christa, Thanks for your response. I don't understand. Are you telling me to delet the className text or the ref?

Comment: delete de ref is not usefull

Comment: Are you saying that the typing is correct, but that my use of ref is incorrect? The element I've placed the ref on is the element I want to track in the react dom. Would you suggest using forwardRef?

Comment: **ref={(element: HTMLDivElement) => noteRefs.current?.push(element)}** the noteRefs contain an array of html elements and not the reference of element

Comment: Yes your use of useRef is wrong you don't use it for an array you use it for an induvial  element, not for multiple.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with you Jesse. There must be a way to generate refs dynamically no?

Comment: Perhaps, I'm too close minded, I'll have a look, maybe you're right.

Comment: you want when the user click outside ? <div ref={ref} className="flex gap-2 bg-yellow-400">
      <input className="text-black" type="text" value={note.task} />
      <input checked={note.status} onChange={inputHandler} type="checkbox" />
    </div> or outside div of className="m-5 grid gap-5"

Comment: Hi Christa, yes, that's correct. Each Note component contains the 'task' which will either display as an input or as a p tag. When the user is in input mode, if they click out the task will display as a p tag.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is how you solve you problem because you are adding unnecessary code and you can delete noteRefs and access to the parent HTML element from the child using ref?.current?.parentElement :

[image]

```
import React, {
  Dispatch,
  SetStateAction,
  useCallback,
  useEffect,
  useRef,
  useState
} from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function assertIsNode(e: EventTarget | null): asserts e is Node {
  if (!e || !("nodeType" in e)) {
    throw new Error(`Node expected`);
  }
}

export interface ITask {
  id?: string;
  task?: string;
  status?: boolean;
}

interface INoteProps {
  note: ITask;
  toDos: ITask[];
  setToDos: Dispatch<SetStateAction<ITask[]>>;
}

const list = [
  {
    id: "1a1",
    task: "wash dishes",
    status: true
  },
  {
    id: "7bs",
    task: "cook dinner",
    status: false
  },
  {
    id: "45q",
    task: "Study",
    status: true
  }
];

const Note = ({ note, toDos, setToDos }: INoteProps) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const handleClickOutside = useCallback(
    (e: MouseEvent) => {
      console.log("clicking anywhere");
      assertIsNode(e.target);
      if (ref?.current?.parentElement?.contains(e.target)) {
        // inside click
        console.log("clicked!");

        return;
      }
      console.log(open);

      // outside click
      setOpen(false);
    },
    [open]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (open) {
      document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    } else {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    }

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, [open, handleClickOutside]);

  // note comes from the note object mapped in app
  // const [input, setInput] = useState<string | undefined>(note.task);

  function inputHandler() {
    setToDos(
      toDos.map((task) => {
        return task ? { ...task, status: !task.status } : task;
      })
    );
  }

  return (
    <div ref={ref} className="flex gap-2 bg-yellow-400">
      <input
        className="text-black"
        type="text"
        value={note.task}
        onChange={() => console.log("")}
      />
      <input checked={note.status} onChange={inputHandler} type="checkbox" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [toDos, setTodos] = useState<ITask[]>(list);
  return (
    <div className="bg-blue-500 h-screen">
      <h2>To do</h2>
      {/* <NoteForm inputHandler={inputHandler} setTodos={setTodos} /> */}
      {toDos.map((note, index) => {
        return (
          <div className="m-5 grid gap-5" key={note.id}>
            <Note note={note} toDos={toDos} setToDos={setTodos} />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

you can check the sandbox :

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-4xgw9z?file=/src/App.tsx:0-2556

or more clean simple way :

remove div wrapper from :

```
return (
      <Note key={note.id} note={note} toDos={toDos} setToDos={setTodos} />
    );
```

and add it inside the note component just like so :

```
import React, {
  Dispatch,
  SetStateAction,
  useCallback,
  useEffect,
  useRef,
  useState
} from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function assertIsNode(e: EventTarget | null): asserts e is Node {
  if (!e || !("nodeType" in e)) {
    throw new Error(`Node expected`);
  }
}

export interface ITask {
  id?: string;
  task?: string;
  status?: boolean;
}

interface INoteProps {
  note: ITask;
  toDos: ITask[];
  setToDos: Dispatch<SetStateAction<ITask[]>>;
}

const list = [
  {
    id: "1a1",
    task: "wash dishes",
    status: true
  },
  {
    id: "7bs",
    task: "cook dinner",
    status: false
  },
  {
    id: "45q",
    task: "Study",
    status: true
  }
];

const Note = ({ note, toDos, setToDos }: INoteProps) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const handleClickOutside = useCallback(
    (e: MouseEvent) => {
      console.log("clicking anywhere");
      assertIsNode(e.target);
      if (ref?.current?.contains(e.target)) {
        // inside click
        console.log("clicked!");

        return;
      }
      console.log(open);

      // outside click
      setOpen(false);
    },
    [open]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (open) {
      document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    } else {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    }

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, [open, handleClickOutside]);

  // note comes from the note object mapped in app
  // const [input, setInput] = useState<string | undefined>(note.task);

  function inputHandler() {
    setToDos(
      toDos.map((task) => {
        return task ? { ...task, status: !task.status } : task;
      })
    );
  }

  return (
    <div ref={ref} className="m-5 grid gap-5">
      {!open ? (
        <div onClick={() => setOpen(true)}> {note.task} </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="flex gap-2 bg-yellow-400">
          <input
            className="text-black"
            type="text"
            value={note.task}
            onChange={() => console.log("")}
          />
          <input
            checked={note.status}
            onChange={inputHandler}
            type="checkbox"
          />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [toDos, setTodos] = useState<ITask[]>(list);
  return (
    <div className="bg-blue-500 h-screen">
      <h2>To do</h2>
      {/* <NoteForm inputHandler={inputHandler} setTodos={setTodos} /> */}
      {toDos.map((note, index) => {
        return (
          <Note key={note.id} note={note} toDos={toDos} setToDos={setTodos} />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer Christa. I'm accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback } from "react";

function assertIsNode(e: EventTarget | null): asserts e is Node {
  if (!e || !("nodeType" in e)) {
    throw new Error(`Node expected`);
  }
}

export interface ITask {
  id?: string;
  task?: string;
  status?: boolean;
}

const list = [
  {
    id: "1a1",
    task: "wash dishes",
    status: true,
  },
  {
    id: "7bs",
    task: "cook dinner",
    status: false,
  },
  {
    id: "45q",
    task: "Study",
    status: true,
  },
];

function App() {
  const noteRefs = useRef<(HTMLDivElement | null)[]>([]);
  const [toDos, setTodos] = useState<ITask[]>(list);

  useEffect(() => {
    noteRefs.current = noteRefs.current.slice(0, toDos.length);
  }, [toDos]);

  return (
    <div className="bg-blue-500 h-screen">
      <h2>To do</h2>
      {toDos.map((note, index) => {
        return (
          <div
            className="m-5 grid gap-5"
            key={note.id}
          >
            <ForwardedNote
              note={note}
              index={index}
              toDos={toDos}
              setToDos={setTodos}
              ref={element => (noteRefs.current[index] = element)}
            />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

interface INoteProps {
  note: ITask;
  toDos: ITask[];
  setToDos: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<ITask[]>>;
  index: number;
}

function Note(
  { note, toDos, setToDos, index }: INoteProps,
  ref: React.ForwardedRef<HTMLDivElement>
) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleClickOutside = useCallback(
    (e: MouseEvent) => {
      console.log("clicking anywhere");
      assertIsNode(e.target);
      if (ref?.current?.contains(e.target)) {
        console.log("clicked inside!");
        return;
      }
      console.log(open);
      setOpen(false);
    },
    [open, ref]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (open) {
      document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    } else {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    }

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, [open, handleClickOutside]);

  function inputHandler() {
    setToDos(
      toDos.map(task => {
        return task ? { ...task, status: !task.status } : task;
      })
    );
  }

  return (
    <div ref={ref} className="flex gap-2 bg-yellow-400">
      <input className="text-black" type="text" value={note.task} readOnly />
      <input
        checked={note.status}
        onChange={inputHandler}
        type="checkbox"
        readOnly
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const ForwardedNote = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, INoteProps>(Note);

export default App;
```

**Output**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback } from "react";
function assertIsNode(e) {
    if (!e || !("nodeType" in e)) {
        throw new Error(`Node expected`);
    }
}
const list = [
    {
        id: "1a1",
        task: "wash dishes",
        status: true,
    },
    {
        id: "7bs",
        task: "cook dinner",
        status: false,
    },
    {
        id: "45q",
        task: "Study",
        status: true,
    },
];
function App() {
    const noteRefs = useRef([]);
    const [toDos, setTodos] = useState(list);
    useEffect(() => {
        noteRefs.current = noteRefs.current.slice(0, toDos.length);
    }, [toDos]);
    return (React.createElement("div", { className: "bg-blue-500 h-screen" },
        React.createElement("h2", null, "To do"),
        toDos.map((note, index) => {
            return (React.createElement("div", { className: "m-5 grid gap-5", key: note.id },
                React.createElement(ForwardedNote, { note: note, index: index, toDos: toDos, setToDos: setTodos, ref: element => (noteRefs.current[index] = element) })));
        })));
}
function Note({ note, toDos, setToDos, index }, ref) {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const handleClickOutside = useCallback((e) => {
        var _a;
        console.log("clicking anywhere");
        assertIsNode(e.target);
        if ((_a = ref === null || ref === void 0 ? void 0 : ref.current) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.contains(e.target)) {
            console.log("clicked inside!");
            return;
        }
        console.log(open);
        setOpen(false);
    }, [open, ref]);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (open) {
            document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
        }
        else {
            document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
        }
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
        };
    }, [open, handleClickOutside]);
    function inputHandler() {
        setToDos(toDos.map(task => {
            return task ? Object.assign(Object.assign({}, task), { status: !task.status }) : task;
        }));
    }
    return (React.createElement("div", { ref: ref, className: "flex gap-2 bg-yellow-400" },
        React.createElement("input", { className: "text-black", type: "text", value: note.task, readOnly: true }),
        React.createElement("input", { checked: note.status, onChange: inputHandler, type: "checkbox", readOnly: true })));
}
const ForwardedNote = React.forwardRef(Note);
export default App;
```

**Compiler Options**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "target": "ES2017",
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

**Playground Link:** [Provided](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxLZFICiAZvUhtccva0gMIoA2vAI3QBrOAF849KBBBwARFFQY5AbgBQa+vgB2GYBG1wUhYrACShAHIQAJkgAUSAFxxaANyTaYAFRRQA5kjwAD5w2vj8AJQuxqYwhHBIcMAJ1na4anDJ9HD2AIRJwaF59nLatkjeAJ5gSHLJhkiRkRlZWTAAFtIA7mFIvbRQ0lD2AAZpSUgAHrUYSDajkepZYmqratOQsA2UUPToSWa+hKI4mck2APwuhDBQwNr+y3DkJ9dwt-ePz7cURO8CCAQXiobTqdZoAy3OC8FLwAC8cAA2uczm0Li45ABGFBYuSYc7tYzCTHdYwdOA2FIdJCEfGEj7kGBEFx3fBUc5iAlZNFtYA2TEAdgEdO5bVeJPkkIgoip2m0SCg9PRv2ZhBc+14xDFXNRDP5mIALABWACOyvFxMxZHwNiqFqyqpZLyg7J1BIAuupNDo9AY4ABBMBgewtXmQ7TQ8qUdgJRE0dgAHnsAAlvABZAAyABFgG5aCCQJ4QmEIrxIkiPQA+eyVpbnCPQpEwCDZiCEbDEHy2dseuDx4hkChIRNHYmVmuw271840BhMDD2UP9qutNrRpCxgB0aHwQ2L-bCEBjSHohB3e8UXi3hFhaAcAAZsC22+eQY9OvWVthm63ezOskUZkoEMewGUTKk3DgNBeFiSwUCLeE5AEfwAFoBF4dlUONB8HzgDpUMINBFE8OQqwZLJEw6AAmKtvAgSkIETAB6GjyPRHkX3bLcQBQEN7A3bAHjsKYWnhVdeQ4uAgL3UCKI4iC83kqSYLghCkCQkBsLgfx7hsHS+OwuRlI44QkCqeEcA3Ld+VWKT0XY+z0UTAAxaAySgOwbGsSgTKkjdLI3OynI44TpkssKpmCkLxT-QhLK4whopij4gno19LK7eibHbZKYsUehLKQQsD3E3IN23Xd9y8JFIr7RFiqQIsvEiPL7OYxynJYyDOo4r8OLEVrwOYnrznrdYHl2fZ7zgMwfKQAAFaQwASXkNxcMcTmeRKNuOYRKx+NK4pcZB0BgLdc0IMAKDQDpE1OjAtxIIIh0oAM-W0Uc9onKtnkilxwhAARFXBDQtF0GB9EMeawJ5I9KGfOLOyO18hO0ETxA2+alogFaxQKk6lHOtyoA8rykzTLNc3zEqvHIsMGyheAkVxzxkZgAB5WptHqghByZBxNWIADoKZ-CUHRkEuDvYQOfweJ+SSAduD4QQRFhtpHBcdMIDnDwWpXNd0UbYEkC3XgIH8UoYOANBhAefwjG0KpuhpRQ5H69FYkVGALAmRwt3IAIgk9vkcnsArLgvaqYCjiNyAeQgA6DwIYGaI2OJNkFzct62ZfmBpCEVvIPeeKSZJAsu2jarOzYtq3We0UPHSCLnPHsIWmir3V0RZ7nsAKj0xu9LI50YZgYCXMSJP1cPG4ZqSct3ZrzpQGwbHcYtMzhTxFVKEBdeIHLum0fFxcl7gZblhW7FDiRiuIDOsiX-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)

Comment: Because I need to make an array of refs. Current will be an array of HTMLDivElements.

Comment: You can't have an array of refs just create multiple refs.

Comment: What if I don't know how many refs I will need? I.e dynamic refs.

Comment: Try this `(HTMLInputElement | null)[]`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: Try the new version I edited it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255135/discussion-between-jesse-and-lauro235).